# Active storage returns attached? as true in console but on rails server it return false

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am new to rails `ActiveStorage` and facing some issues in image uploading. 
while i try to upload image it uploaded successfully but when i try to get the image it returns attached as false. But when i try same record in console it return the image url.

[image: Console output]

Rails server output:

[image: Rails server output]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation when I had multiple records attached to the same blob.

Not sure if that's what happened here, if you had 2 companies using the same attachment, and then purged that attachment from one record, it will delete both the blob reference and file itself, **without removing other associated blobs**. This means one record will still sometimes think it has a file attached (as it's still associated with a blob)

A good way to find out is to check out in rails console:

```
obj.image.blob.filename
```

This will show if the actual file that's associated with an object exists, rather than just its blob. It's a bug in Active Storage that they're apparently addressing, not sure if it applies here or not.